# Как сделать оптимизацию обработки даты в цикле?

Tags: javascript

Кажется этот вызов очень сильно влияет на скорость

`new Date(now.setHours(now.getHours() - 1));`

Наверное из за того что постоянно в цикле переопределяется дата.

Если еще какой нибудь вариант чтобы вычесть каждый час из даты и записать в объект?

```js
function randomData() {
  let now = new Date();
  let data = {};
  for (let j = 0; j <= 500; j++) {
    if (j) now = new Date(now.setHours(now.getHours() - 1));
    let d = ('0'+ now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    let m = ('0'+ (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    let y = now.getFullYear();
    let h = ('0'+ now.getHours()).slice(-2);
    data[j] = {
      timestamp: `${y}-${m}-${d} ${h}:00:00`,
      price: 120.24
    };
  }
  return data;
}
console.log(randomData());
```

Comment: _Кажется этот вызов очень сильно влияет на скорость_ - почему ты так думаешь?

Comment: [.setHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) меняет объект, нет нужды вызывать `new Date` на результате